# Missing tag functionality for questions that have been edited

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, tooltips

Currently, on questions that have been edited ([random example](https://superuser.com/q/550155/380318)) or, sometimes, that have answers edited by someone other than the answer's writer ([random example](https://superuser.com/q/936432/380318)):

- The 10K "edit tags" link does not appear when I put my mouse to the right of the tags
- Mousing over the tags to see their wiki excerpt does nothing other than display the "show questions tagged" tooltip

Questions with no editing involved ([random example](https://superuser.com/q/267444/380318)) work fine.

On questions where the error occurs, the Chrome console shows `Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function` in `full.en.js`, with a long run highlighted that starts with this:

```
:t(c.getMinutes())})}function a(e){var t=$("<div />");return t.text(e),t.html().replace('"',"&quot;")
```

I'm using Google Chrome 50.0.2661.102 on 64-bit Windows 8.1 at 1920x1080. I can only reproduce this issue on the site where I have 10K (Super User).

Comment: Can't reproduce here. Check the browser's JS console and network tab when reloading, sounds like a borked or missing client side script.

Comment: Ah, there is indeed an error in the console. I've added it to the question.

Comment: What happens to the error if you hard refresh (Ctrl + F5)?

Comment: @Oded It goes away, and the problem is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that it went away after a hard refresh:

http://shouldiblamecaching.com/